# 5 different mangoes 4 different oranges and 3 different apples be distributed among 3 children such that each gets at least one mango?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can $5$ different mangoes $4$ different oranges and $3$ different apples be distributed among $3$ children such that each gets at least one mango?
My try:
I selected any $3$ mangoes from 5 by $\binom{5}{3}$ and arranged them by multiplying $3!$. Now the remaining fruits are 2 mangoes, 4 oranges and 3 apples (all distinct). These 9 objects can be distributed among 3 children in $3^9$ ways. So, final answer should be $\binom{5}{3}\cdot3!\cdot3^9$ but my answer is wrong.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You went wrong in distributing mangoes and created a lot of duplicate arrangements by first picking $3$ mangoes, arranging them and then distributing other two mangoes as part of the rest.

Comment: I did that so that each child receives at least 1 mango and then the other fruits can be distributed in any way.

Comment: To corroborate on Math Lover's statement, Let's say the 5 mangoes are A, B, C, D, E. Let's say you select A, B, and C as the initial 3 mangoes that are distributed and then you give the child with A mangoes D and E. You can get this same distribution by selecting D, B, and C as the initial 3 mangoes that are distributed and giving the child with D mangoes A and E. Hence, you are overcounting.

Comment: yes we know why you did it but I hope Alan Abraham's explanation clarifies it. There are multiple ways you can fix it. Some of them being - Apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion, directly use Stirling Number of the second kind, or carefully work case by case - if all of them get at least one mange, only possibilities are $(2, 2, 1)$ or $(3, 1, 1)$

Answer (score 4):

We can see that the process of distributing each fruit is independent of each other, so we can just multiply the number of distributions for each fruit for the total number of distributions.

As you have already noted, the number of ways to distribute the 7 fruits that are not mangoes is $3^7$.

The number of ways to distribute the 5 mangoes will be $3!S(5,3)$, where $S(n,k)$ is the stirling numbers of the second kind. There are several ways to go about computing this: using a table of values, using the recurrence, using the explicit formula, or generating functions. I'll just show the generating functions method, as the other ones are rather trivial to apply if you already know the formula.

This is the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of
$$5!(x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\ldots)^3$$
Using the taylor series of $e^x$, we get that this is equivalent to the coefficient of $x^5$ in
$$5!(e^x-1)^3$$
$$5!(e^{3x}-3e^{2x}+3e^x-1)$$
Since the coefficient of $x^5$ in $e^{kx}$ is $\frac{k^5}{5!}$, this is equivalent to
$$3^5-3\cdot 2^5+3$$
$$150$$
Hopefully you see the semblance to the explicit formula for the stirling numbers of the second kind.

This means that the number of ways to distribute the mangoes is $150$ and the number of ways to distribute all $12$ fruits is $\boxed{150\cdot 3^7}$.

Comment: Even case-wise is straightforward here - $(3, 1, 1)$ or $(2, 2, 1)$

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I just wanted to provide a more generalized solution. If we just want to straight forward count we could note that the number of ways to sum $3$ numbers to $5$ is either the permutations of $(3,1,1)$ (there are $3$ of those) or $(2,2,1)$ (there are also $3$ of those). There are $\binom{5}{3,1,1}=20$ and $\binom{5}{2,2,1}=30$ ways to distribute the mangoes in the two ways respectively. Hence, the total is $3\cdot 20+3\cdot 30=150$

Comment: @MathLover +1 to the answer and +1 to both of the above comments : nice discussion.